# Why cant i call the contract entry point with type parameter througth eztz.contract.send

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, error, eztz, micheline

im trying to call the entry point create_proposition ...

```
(pair :proposition %_Liq_entry_create_proposition
        (key_hash %destination)
        (mutez %amount))
```

using the function eztz.contract.send, this is the function ...

```
eztz.contract
    .send(
      contractaddress,
      "tz1ddb9NMYHZi5UzPdzTZMYQQZoMub195zgv",
      keysextracted,
      5,
      '(Left (Pair ("' + address + '" ' + amount + ")))",
      1000000,
      400000,
      10000
    )
```

I know that there error is the parameter i just don't know hot o fix it, can anyone help me?

this is my parameter and storage in Michelson...

```
parameter
  (or :_entries
     (pair :proposition %_Liq_entry_create_proposition
        (key_hash %destination)
        (mutez %amount))
     (or (unit %_Liq_entry_sign_proposition) (unit %_Liq_entry_execute_proposition)));
storage
  (pair :storage
     (set %owners address)
     (pair (set %owners_signed address)
           (option %last_proposition
              (pair :proposition (key_hash %destination) (mutez %amount)))));
```

im using the protocol3.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem just know, the thing here was that i didn't realize until i noticed how i was receiving the balance of the contract that i had to send the atomized value of the amount in tez.

So basically the conversion is quite simple ...

You want the atomized value:
 value(int/float) * 1 000 000

You want the int/float value instead of the atomized one:
 value(atomic) / 1 000 000

So basically my function looks like this now ....

```
eztz.contract
    .send(
      contractAdd,
      "tz1ddb9NMYHZi5UzPdzTZMYQQZoMub195zgv",
      keysext,
      5,
      '(Left (Pair "' + address + '" ' + amount(atomized value) + "))",
      1000000,
      400000,
      60000
    )
```